# What is the rate limit for IBM's Document Conversion Service and how do I increase it?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, document-conversion

We use IBM's *Document Conversion* service as a core part of our Watson-based AI system. Recently I have been getting a lot of this error whilst building our corpus:

> Error SLM-THROTTLE occurred when accessing
>   https://158.85.132.88:443/document-conversion/api/v1/convert_document?version=2015-12-15,
>   Tran-Id: gateway-dp01-416345942 - You have reached the request rate
>   limit, please wait and try again later

Can someone tell me what the limit is, and can it be increased?

Comment: Wouldn't IBM support be in the best position to tell you this??

Comment: IBM Bluemix Support and Development actively monitor ibm-bluemix tagged questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Document Conversion Service has currently an overall (universal) rate limit of 2,700 concurrent requests. Generally, when you get "rate limit reached" errors we recommend retrying with backoff between retries. This is something that you can implement programmatically in your application.

Out of curiosity, how many concurrent conversion requests is your application sending?

Comment: Thanks, that's the information I was looking for. When you say "universal", does that mean all users, or just per account?  I doubt if we're sending that many.  Our application limits them to 10 at a time.

Comment: Yes, by "universal" I mean across all users of the service.